# My music bot is not detecting my response?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Yo! A year and a half ago i coded a music system on discord.js everything was working fine but today when the bot returns me youtube search results i can't choose which one i want to play.

The bot does not detect my response, and sends me a message that I have not chosen a music. please help me i can't find the error for two days

discord.js version 12.3.1

````
const YouTube = require('simple-youtube-api');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

const youtube = new YouTube(config.GOOGLE_API_KEY);

const queue = new Map();


bot.on('message', async message => { // eslint-disable-line
    if (message.author.bot) return undefined;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return undefined;

    const args = message.content.split(' ');
    const searchString = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    const url = args[1] ? args[1].replace(/<(.+)>/g, '$1') : '';
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

    let command = message.content.toLowerCase().split(' ')[0];
    command = command.slice(config.prefix.length)

    if (command === 'play') {
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send(`⛔ **Veuillez vous connecter à un salon vocal !**`);
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) {
            return message.channel.send(`⛔ **Je ne peux pas me connecter, veuillez vérifier que j'ai les bonnes permissions !**`);
        }
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
            return message.channel.send(`⛔ **Je ne peux pas parler danc ce salon, veuillez vérifier que j'ai les bonnes permissions !**`);
        }

        if (url.match(/^https?:\/\/(www.youtube.com|youtube.com)\/playlist(.*)$/)) {
            const playlist = await youtube.getPlaylist(url);
            const videos = await playlist.getVideos();
            for (const video of Object.values(videos)) {
                const video2 = await youtube.getVideoByID(video.id); // eslint-disable-line no-await-in-loop
                await handleVideo(video2, message, voiceChannel, true); // eslint-disable-line no-await-in-loop
            }
            return message.channel.send(`**✅ Playlist: __${playlist.title}__ à bien été ajoutée dans la queue !**`);
        } else {
            try {
                var video = await youtube.getVideo(url);
            } catch (error) {
                try {
                    var videos = await youtube.searchVideos(searchString, 10);
                    let index = 0;
                    message.channel.send(`
__**Résultats de la recherche :**__
${videos.map(video2 => `**${++index} -** ${video2.title}`).join('\n')}
Veuillez sélectionner l'un des résultats, allant de 1 à 10.
                    `);
                    // eslint-disable-next-line max-depth
                    try {
                        var response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(
                            msg2 => (msg2.content > 0 && msg2.content < 11, {
                            maxMatches: 1,
                            time: 60000,
                            errors: ['time']
                        })
                      );
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return message.channel.send(':no_entry: **Aucun ou un numéro invalide a été sélectionné, annulation de la recherche.**');
                    }
                    const videoIndex = parseInt(response.first().content);
                    
                    var video = await youtube.getVideoByID(videos[videoIndex - 1].id);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return message.channel.send(` **Je n'ai pu obtenir des résultats.**`);
                }
            }
            return handleVideo(video, message, voiceChannel);
        }
    } else if (command === 'skip') {
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(`⛔ **Il n'y a rien que je puisse passer pour vous.**`);
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end('La commande skip a bien été utilisée.');
        return undefined;
    } else if (command === 'stop') {
        let bureauBot = bot.channels.cache.get("629993073929224192");
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(`⛔ **Il n'y a rien que je puisse arrêter pour vous.**`);
        serverQueue.songs = [];
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end('La commande stop à bien été utilisée.');
        bureauBot.join()
        return undefined;
    } else if (command === 'volume') {
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(`:no_entry: **Il n'y a rien qui est joué.**`);
        if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send(`**Le volume actuel est de : **${serverQueue.volume}**`);
        serverQueue.volume = args[1];
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(args[1] / 5);
        return message.channel.send(`:loud_sound: **J'ai mis le volume à : ${args[1]}**`);
    } else if (command === 'shazam') {
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(`:no_entry: **Il n'y a rien qui est joué.**`);
        return message.channel.send(` **Il est actuellement joué : ${serverQueue.songs[0].title}**`);
    } else if (command === 'queue') {
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send(`:no_entry: **Il n'y a rien qui est joué.**`);
        return message.channel.send(`
__**Queue:**__
${serverQueue.songs.map(song => `**-** ${song.title}`).join('\n')}
** Actuellement joué : __${serverQueue.songs[0].title}__**
        `);
    } else if (command === 'pause') {
        if (serverQueue && serverQueue.playing) {
            serverQueue.playing = false;
            serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.pause();
            return message.channel.send(`⏸ **J'ai mis la musique en pause pour vous.**`);
        }
        return message.channel.send(`:no_entry: **Il n'y a rien qui est joué.**`);
    } else if (command === 'resume') {
        if (serverQueue && !serverQueue.playing) {
            serverQueue.playing = true;
            serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.resume();
            return message.channel.send(`▶️ **J'ai repris la musique pour vous.**`);
        }
        return message.channel.send(`:no_entry: **Il n'y a rien qui est joué.**`);
    }

    return undefined;
});

async function handleVideo(video, message, voiceChannel, playlist = false) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    console.log(video);
    const song = {
        id: video.id,
        title: Util.escapeMarkdown(video.title),
        url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id}`
    };
    if (!serverQueue) {
        const queueConstruct = {
            textChannel: message.channel,
            voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
            connection: null,
            songs: [],
            volume: 5,
            playing: true
        };
        queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);

        queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

        try {
            var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            queueConstruct.connection = connection;
            play(message.guild, queueConstruct.songs[0]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
            queue.delete(message.guild.id);
            return message.channel.send(`⛔ **Je ne peux pas rejoindre le salon vocal : __${error}__**`);
        }
    } else {
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        console.log(serverQueue.songs);
        if (playlist) return undefined;
        else return message.channel.send(`✅ **__${song.title}__ a bien été ajouté à la queue.**`);
    }
    return undefined;
}

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

    if (!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    console.log(serverQueue.songs);

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url))
        .on('finish', reason => {
            if (reason === 'Stream is not generating quickly enough.') message.channel.send(' **Musique terminée.**');
            else console.log(reason);
            serverQueue.songs.shift();
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on('error', error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);

    serverQueue.textChannel.send(`:notes: **Je commence a jouer : __${song.title}__**`);
}```
````

Comment: That's a lot of code. Could you show us where exactly the problem is happening?

Comment: Hello @Lioness100, I have no error but I think the problem is due to the response system:
var response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(
                            msg2 => (msg2.content > 0 && msg2.content < 11, {
                            maxMatches: 1,
                            time: 60000,
                            errors: ['time']
                        })
                      );
                    }
or with the videoIndex :
const videoIndex = parseInt(response.first().content);

I'm not sure but I strongly suspect that it comes from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set up the [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) function wrong. The entire [`options`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AwaitMessagesOptions) object is in your [`filter`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorFilter) function for some reason. Also, you're comparing the string, [`message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content), to a number. Maybe you meant to compare the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)? Another note is that you used a `maxMatches` property in your `options` object, which is not valid. Did you mean `max`, or `maxProcessed`.

```js
var response = await message.channel.awaitMessages(
 (msg2) => msg2.content.length > 0 && msg2.content.length < 11, // end the function here
 { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] } // `max` instead of `maxMatches`
);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much <3